# MP4 video won't play in JWPlayer

Tags: video, jwplayer, jwplayer6, jwplayer7

I am converting (re-encoding) video files using HandBrakeCLI
The the converted file is H264 mp4 video. I can play the converted video using VLC, Windows Media, QuickTime etc but it won't play in JW Player (both version 6.x and 7.2.2 fail)

It says Error loading media: File could not be played.

I looked at the error message in longtail site which says this may occur if the video format is incorrect (webm, mov, wmv) but not for mp4 file.

Since I am getting mp4 file, why jwplayer fails?

Same player can play other mp4 video that I convert. It only failing for certain mp4.

Here is my handbrake command:

```
-i "..\uploads\<videoid>\mike & molly.mp4" -o "..\videos\mike & molly.mp4" -e x264 -q 20 -B 160 --maxWidth 800 --maxHeight 450 --optimize
```

Please help.

Comment: Looks like an & in the file name causing this error, but jw player can't handle ampersand in file name?

Comment: If I change the file name from "mike & molly.mp4" to "mike molly.mp4", it plays fine!! How can I handle & and other special characters so that JWPlayer can handle all of them including unicode characters?

Comment: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue putting certain characters in my jwplayer container's id name. My fix was to change to a static name with no characters, but in your case you need to html encode and decode the characters.

OR

Have you tried escaping the characters using '\' or '^'?

```
ie: -i "..\uploads\<videoid>\mike \& molly.mp4" -o "
ie: -i "..\uploads\<videoid>\mike ^& molly.mp4" -o "
```